# pendingIntent not sending extras, despite the flags

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

My pendingIntent is carrying no extras to the service, despite the flags I put in the intent or the pendingIntent itself.

DrawerActivity.class:

```
@Override
public void registerAlarmTask(Calendar time, String title, int iconId) {

    int requestId = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("title",title);
    intent.putExtra("icon", iconId);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    intent.setAction("alarm");
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar newTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    newTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, time.get(Calendar.MINUTE)-1);

    alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, newTime.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);
    Log.w(TAG, "Alarm created! " + newTime.toString());
}
```

And the StartCommand method from NotificationService:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder nBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        Log.w(TAG, "Icon ID: " + intent.getIntExtra("icon", 404) + " / Title: " + intent.getStringExtra("title"));
        nBuilder.setSmallIcon(intent.getIntExtra("icon", R.drawable.ic_event_new));
        nBuilder.setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("title"));
        nBuilder.setContentText("A partida irá começar em instantes...");
        nBuilder.setTicker("Sua partida no Destiny está prestes a começar!");
        nBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nManager.notify(0, nBuilder.build());

    Log.w(TAG, "Notification Service started!");
    Toast.makeText(this, "Notification Service started!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

The extras from the intent are always null, no matter the requestId, intent flags or pendingIntent flags i put.

Any tip in where I'm doing wrong? I've searched a lot, but found no answer.

Regards,
Lucas Sene

Comment: I had this same issue and banged my head against the wall for some time to get it working. There are supposedly flags to enable on the Pending Intent but they would never work properly for me, despite being documented. Instead I ended up using a local sql lite database because I couldn't get the PendingIntent to properly send data via the provided methods. Wish I had a more technical answer for you, best of luck.

Comment: Your `PendingIntent` is broadcasting to a `BroadcastReceiver`, from which you're presumably starting your `Service`. The extras attached to the `Intent` delivered to the Receiver need to be attached to the `Intent` used to start the `Service`. They won't automatically be forwarded for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mike M. said in the comments, I just forgot to pass the Intent extra from the BroadcastReceiver to the Service. Yes, a silly mistake...

Thanks for all comments!